# Binary classifier peaks around 0.5 for signal, still gives decent separation

Tags: python, classification, random-forest, xgboost, decision-tree

I'm using XGBoost for binary classification. I plot the classifier output for being class A. It peaks on zero for class B, but it always peaks around 0.5 for class A.

Still, it gives decent -but not stellar- separation, as evidenced by the ROC curve.

Is this behaviour normal or expected in some way? Or does not peaking on 1 mean that something is definitely wrong with the model?

**Edit:**

Following Jon's tip in the comments, I found out that when I implement balancing of the two unbalanced classes (with scale_pos_weight), the classifier output looks more proper indeed, with the peak moving from 0.5 to 1. *However* this happens only when I run without folds.

When I run with folds, I [read](https://machinelearningmastery.com/cross-validation-for-imbalanced-classification/) that instead of balancing one should use stratification. I tried this out by using `StratifiedKFold` instead of `KFold`. Unfortunately this doesn't change the situation.

Please note that my original question still holds, both in the folds and no folds case: Even when the peak moves to 1, was having it at 0.5 wrong?

Comment: How well balanced are the classes?

Comment: @JonNordby Good point, they are not, 1:4 for A to B. (When I try scale_pos_weight the results degrade.)

Comment: For debugging the max=0.5 problem alone I would try to balance the classes - dropping samples from the majority class is the safest.

Comment: @JonNordby Let me be back!

Comment: @JonNordby please take a look at the edit.

Comment: What do you mean by "it peaks"?